# How I can use CMake for linking Python 2 and Python 3 libraries for a same software

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake, python-2.x

I am developing an IDE with plugins to support Python 2 and Python 3. The build system is CMake.

The problem is when CMake looks for Python 2, the Python variables will point to Python 2 paths. But now I need get the paths to Python 3 too.

Does anyone knows if it is possible to do that? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I could to find a solution. Just create a FindPythonLibs3 to look for Python 3 paths and set new variables for each path. It will be possible to use these paths for Python 3 and the others for Python 2 without conflict.